# SideBarGit missing from Package Install on Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Also GitGutter's features are not working (icons not showing up).

I am new to SublimeText 2, I did install Package Control 2 and set Git/bin/ to PATH in variables in Windows 8 and it works on command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [`SideBarGit`'s page](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SideBarGit) on the Package Control website, you'll see that it's for Sublime Text 3 only.